# Resgatar o valor de um input com echo do loop de um while

Tags: php

Gostaria de resgatar o valor de um `input` com `echo` do *loop* de um `while` e solicitar *UPDATE* resgatando esse valor.

```
<form method="POST" name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                        <?php while ($linhasMotoristas = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaMotoristas)) {
                                $motoristasStatus = $linhasMotoristas['status'];
                                $motoristasId = $linhasMotoristas['idmotoristas'];
                                $motoristasNome = $linhasMotoristas['nome'];
                                $motoristasCpf = $linhasMotoristas['cpf'];
                                $motoristasGanhos = $linhasMotoristas['ganhos']
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="s">
                                        <?php 
                                    if($motoristasStatus == 1){
                                        echo "<div style='color: green;'>●</div>";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<div style='color: red;'>●</div>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="m"><?php echo $motoristasId;?></td>
                                    <td class="n"><?php echo $motoristasNome;?></td>
                                    <td class="c"><input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="<?php echo $motoristasId;?>"><?php echo $motoristasCpf;?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="g"><?php echo round($motoristasGanhos, 2);?></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <?php
                                        if (isset($_POST['submit'])?$_POST['submit'] : 0) {
                                        $cpfMotorista = $_POST['td_1'];
                                        $valorBruto = $_POST['valorBruto'];
                                        $porcentagemBase = 5/100;
                                        $EncargosBase = 25/100;

                                        $vezesPorcentagem = $valorBruto*$porcentagemBase;
                                        $menosEncargosBase = $vezesPorcentagem-$EncargosBase;
                                        $resultadoLiquido = $menosEncargosBase*$porcentagemBase;
                                        $resultadoGeral = $resultadoLiquido;

                                        $inserirBanco = "UPDATE getmoney.motoristas SET ganhos = COALESCE(ganhos, 0) + '$resultadoGeral' WHERE idmotoristas = '$cpfMotorista'";
                                        $execInserirBanco = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserirBanco);
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                        <input type="text" name="valorBruto">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular">
                                        <?php echo $cpfMotorista;?>
                                        <?php echo round($resultadoGeral,2); ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </form>
```

[image: So resgata o ID 25]

Nessa foto, como vocês podem ver, ele só resgata o *ID* 25 e eu queria que, de acordo com a linha, resgatasse o *ID* do usuário e fizesse o *UPDATE* do valor somado no campo `input` de soma...

Comment: Não entendi nada. Esclareça melhor sua duvida.

Comment: <td class="c"><input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="<?php echo $motoristasId;?>"><?php echo $motoristasCpf;?>
                                    </td>

Comment: Gostaria de resgatar esse valor gerado pelo loop em "value="<?php echo $motoristasId;?>" e na hora de usar o calcular quando você pode ver na imagem, fazer update apenas no ID solicitado

Comment: Não estou entendendo seu código, pra mim não tem sentido o que ele faz. Dentro do while resgata valores do formulário e faz update. Sua consulta retorna quantos registros diferentes?

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - coloque colchetes nos `names` dos inputs para que possam ser enviados na forma de array para o receptor.

```
<input type="hidden" name="td_1[]" value="<?php echo $motoristasId; ?>">

<input type="text" name="valorBruto[]">
```

2 - Retire o input submit de dentro do while, coloque-o em uma linha após o fechamento do while

```
<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
```

3 - Ao submeter o formulário recupere os arrays

```
    $valorBruto = $_POST['valorBruto'];

    $motoristasId = $_POST['td_1'];
```

4 - Use um loop for para iterar

```
    $result = count($valorBruto);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {
```

5 - Utilize uma condicional para somente valores `não nulos`

```
    $result = count($valorBruto);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {
    
        if ($valorBruto[$i]!=""){
```

6 - Dentro desse if faça o que deve ser feito :-)

7 - Separe a parte do formulário da parte que vai processar os dados do formulário.

### Código completo

```
<?php

    $conexao = ...........

if (isset($_POST['submit'])?$_POST['submit'] : 0) {

$valorBruto = $_POST['valorBruto'];

$motoristasId = $_POST['td_1'];

    $result = count($valorBruto);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {
    
        if ($valorBruto[$i]!=""){
            $cpfMotorista = $motoristasId[$i];
            $porcentagemBase = 5/100;
            $encargosBase = 25/100;
            $vezesPorcentagem = $valorBruto[$i]*$porcentagemBase;
            $menosEncargosBase = $vezesPorcentagem-$encargosBase;
            $resultadoLiquido = $menosEncargosBase*$porcentagemBase;
            $resultadoGeral = $resultadoLiquido;
            
            $inserirBanco = "UPDATE ...................
            $execInserirBanco = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserirBanco);
        }
    
    }

}
?>

<form method="POST" name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<?php 

$consultaMotoristas = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT...................

while ($linhasMotoristas = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaMotoristas)) {
    $motoristasStatus = $linhasMotoristas['status'];
    $motoristasId = $linhasMotoristas['idmotoristas'];
    $motoristasNome = $linhasMotoristas['nome'];
    $motoristasCpf = $linhasMotoristas['cpf'];
    $motoristasGanhos = $linhasMotoristas['ganhos']
?>
    <tr>
    <td class="s">
        <?php 
        if($motoristasStatus == 1){
        echo "<div style='color: green;'>●</div>";
        }else{echo "<div style='color: red;'>●</div>";
        }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td class="m"><?php echo $motoristasId;?></td>
    <td class="n"><?php echo $motoristasNome;?></td>
    
    <td class="c"><input type="hidden" name="td_1[]" value="<?php echo $motoristasId; ?>">
    </td>
    <td class="g"><?php echo round($motoristasGanhos, 2);?></td>
    <td>                                        
    <input type="text" name="valorBruto[]">
    
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Cara, que Deus te abençoe, muito obrigado!